# How to perform row double click event in kendo ui grid angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

How to display orginal cell value in cell template `<span>` tag in angular 2 kendo ui grid.

**Code**

```
<ng-container ngFor="let col of grid.ColModel">
    <kendo-grid-column [title]="col.Label" [field]="col.Name" [locked]="col.Locked" width="250px" *ngIf="hiddenColumns.indexOf(col.Name) === -1" >
        <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex" >
        <span (dblclick)="open(rowIndex)">**{{dataItem}}** </span>
        </template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: (dblclick)="function here"

Comment: You can use like this: `(dblclick)="func2()"` in kendo grid: `rowTemplate:'<tr (dblclick)="onDblClick()"><td>Click</td></tr>',`

Comment: am using angular 2 kendo grid and i guess they dont have row template

Answer (score 5):

The example provided by Melanie might have worked in the past, but will not work with the Angular 2/4 Grid (if you click on the plunker, it won't load).

I have to do lots of debugging as I ran into the same issue.

The solution in a simple grid was as follows:

```
 <kendo-grid #myGrid [selectable]="true" (dblclick)="dblClickEvent(myGrid, $event)">
 <kendo-grid-column field="User" title="User" width="100">
                    </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

in your .ts file, implement the event as follows:

```
     dblClickEvent(grid, event) {
        // debugger;
      console.log('the selected row Index is '+ event.path[1].rowIndex);
      //use the following line if you want to get the clicked cell content:
console.log('clicked cell content'+ event.path[0].textContent);

}
```

This would give your the selected row index, from which you can

Hope this helps.

Comment: this works for me in chrome, but not in firefox, as in firefox there is no path property on the event. how can we solve that for firefox and chrome?

Answer (score 4):

The first argument in your double-click handler needs to be the double-click event (which you can access as `$event` in your template).  You should pass that first and `rowIndex` second.

In addition, you're probably missing a lot of `click` events since you're using a `span` and your content is inside of a padded cell.  I'd recommend that you make your entire cell a click target, for example by changing it to a `div` and getting rid of the padding on the containing `td`.

So your cell template might look like:

```
<kendo-grid-column field="MyField">
    <template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
        <div class="innerCell" (dblclick)="onRowDoubleClick($event, rowIndex)">
            {{dataItem.MyField}}
         </div>
    </template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

And your function:

```
onRowDoubleClick(evt, rowIndex) {
  alert('You clicked row ' + rowIndex + '!');
}
```

And your styling:

```
td { padding: 0 !important; }
td > .innerCell { padding: 7px; cursor: pointer; }
```

Example: **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BWOGCks7PxmfLW9rH4VH?p=preview)**

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

If you have a sortable grid, you need to implement cellClick and dblClick like here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ac3jzd?file=app/app.component.ts

This works for both: sorted and non sorted kendo grids

**Orginal answer:**

We like to define the dblclick on the grid and not on each column, So the answer from Adam works for us perfectly in chrome, but not in firefox.

Problem is that the path property is non-standard on the mouseevent and not provided in firefox (probably not in safari too)

Based on Adam's solution, we have solved it with:

```
<kendo-grid [selectable]="true" (dblclick)="dblClickEvent($event)">
 <kendo-grid-column field="User" title="User" width="100"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

and:

```
  dblClickEvent(event) {
    let rowIndex;
    if (event.path) { // works on chrome and all browsers supporting path property in mouseevent
      rowIndex = event.path[1].rowIndex;
    } else { // should work on all browsers
      rowIndex = event.target.parentElement.rowIndex;
    }

    if (typeof rowIndex === 'number' && rowIndex < this.data.length) {
      // do something
    }
  }
```

(this aussumes that the user has clicked inside a td-element)

Note: this does not work if the grid was sorted

Comment: do you have any idea about how to perform dblClick event on row?

Comment: @sajadre imho above code does exactly what you want

Comment: @davey What about for firefox?

Comment: @Elizar event.target.parentElement.rowIndex